# How to delete a html-tag in Woocommerce form-checkout

Tags: php, html, woocommerce

Hy,

I want to delete HTML `br` tag from Woocommerce form-checkout. I want to do this so that the text "Ship to a different address?" can go up beside the check-box.
I don't know how to do this .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery

```
$('.input-checkbox').next().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `JS` for this. You can simply hide `br` tag using `CSS`.

```
.woocommerce-shipping-fields .input-checkbox ~ br {
    display: none;
}
```